# Converting an array of bytes into a float32

Tags: javascript, binary, floating-point

I have a JavaScript application which receives a voltage value as an `Uint8Array`. Here are 2 examples of the received data:

```
[3, 134, 46, 177, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[3, 127, 46, 170, 46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I am trying to convert this `Uint8Array` to a float value, but I am not sure if it's a `float32` or `float64`, if it's signed or not.  What I do know is that this value is around 12.

Can anyone help with a JavaScript snippet to do the conversion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the expected output you need for the input you have given?

Comment: Looks like 20 bytes to me, which would be neither `float32` nor `float64`?

Comment: Taking the first 8 bytes gives either 2.843474359893e-312 or 4.021529366771898e-87 (little endian vs. big endian), so I think there is some information missing. If you don't know the exact meaning of the entries: what machine/sensor/library gives you these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line appears to have two voltages in it. Voltages from devices usually come from ATOD converters that have between 8 and 16 bits of info and are scaled based on the circuitry.

It looks like a 3 (unused and probably some sort of mode flag) followed by two pairs of bytes each one a voltage from a ATOD. I would guess that two bytes such as 177 and 46 should be interpreted as (177+46*256)/1000.0 based on 1 mv. scaling. This produces values just over 11.9 volts. Given the range of the two samples this would fit your expectations.